# How to pre-compute SpanTermQuery in lucene?

Tags: lucene

At query time, I almost always get SpanQuery match and was wondering how to pre-compute the window-co-occurance stats. ? Doing this at query time seems to slow down the search time.

```
          SpanTermQuery[] span_query = new SpanTermQuery[3]
          span_query[0] = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("text", "united"));
          span_query[1] = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("text", "states"));
          span_query[2] = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("text", "department"));
          // find a match in unordered window and window-span is 12. 
          SpanNearQuery span_near_query = new SpanNearQuery(span_query, 12, false);
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  If this is a query you reuse frequently, you can cache the results in a [filter](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2009/02/filtering-a-lucene-search.html) to improve performance on subsequent uses.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I mean if I use a lot of phrase queries, I might very well do ShingleWrapperAnalyzer and index the bi-grams and tri-grams. Whats the similar strategy for SpanNearQuery ?